# SAS compare two tables with different column order

Tags: sas

Hi I have two tables with different column orders, and the column name are not capitalized as the same. How can I compare if the contents of these two tables are the same?

For example, I have two tables of students' grades

```
  table A:

        Math   English  History
      -------+--------+---------  
   Tim   98      95        90
  Helen 100      92        85


 table B:

        history   MATH    english
       --------+--------+---------  
   Tim   90       98        95
  Helen  85      100        92
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use either of the two approaches to compare, regardless of the order or column name

```
/*1. Proc compare*/

proc sort data=A; by name; run;
proc sort data=B; by name; run;

proc compare base=A compare=B;
   id name;
run;

/*2. Proc SQL*/
proc sql;
select Math, English, History from A
<union/ intersect/ Except>
select MATH, english, history from B;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

use except corr(corresponding) it will check by name. if everything is matching you will get zero records.

```
 data have1;
 input  Math   English  History;
datalines;
1 2 3
;
run;

data have2;
input English math History;
datalines;
 2 1 3
;
run;



proc sql ;
select * from have1
 except corr
 select * from have2;
```

**edit1**

if you want to check which particular column it differs you may have to transpose and compare as shown below example.

```
data have1;
 input name $ Math   English pyschology History;
 datalines;
  Tim 98      95     76   90
 Helen 100      92   55     85
  ;
 run;

data have2;
input name $ English Math pyschology History;
datalines;
Tim       95   98  76   90
 Helen    92  100 99    85
 ;
run;

 proc sort data = have1 out =hav1;
 by name;
run;

 proc sort data = have2 out =hav2;
 by name;
  run;

 proc transpose data =hav1 out=newhave1 (rename = (_name_= subject 
 col1=marks));
 by name;
  run;

  proc transpose data =hav2 out=newhave2 (rename = (_name_= subject 
 col1=marks));
 by name;
 run;


 proc sql;
create table want(drop=mark_dif) as
 select 
 a.name as name
,a.subject as subject
,a.marks as have1_marks
,b.marks as have2_marks
,a.marks -b.marks as mark_dif
from  newhave1 a inner join newhave2 b
on upcase(a.name)  = upcase(b.name)
and upcase(a.subject) =upcase(b.subject)
where calculated mark_dif ne 0;
```

Comment: thank you! it does work! But is there a way only return the variables that are different?

Comment: For example, if there is one more variable say psychology. Assume it is 80 in have1 and 70 in have2. Can I get a table back only shows the different column, which is psychology.

Comment: i have edited the code to answer how to see which subject it different between tables not all of them.